# How to make Database table?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to do JDBC So I try          [image]

```
mysql> use video_db;
Database changed
mysql> create table videos(
    -> code varchar(10) not null,
    -> title varchar(30),
    -> ganre varchar(30),
    -> releaseDay varchar(10),
    -> isRental char(1),
    -> rentalPrice int(11),
    -> primarykey(code)
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(code)
)' at line 8
```

How can I fix it? plz help me

Comment: Use `PRIMARY KEY (code)` ... you need spaces in there

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space between "primary" and "key":

```
mysql> create table videos(
    -> code varchar(10) not null,
    -> title varchar(30),
    -> ganre varchar(30),
    -> releaseDay varchar(10),
    -> isRental char(1),
    -> rentalPrice int(11),
    -> primary key(code) -- Here!
    -> );
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions.